# Values undefined when using Picklist (After Render Error)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, picklist

Hello I am able to successfully push my LWC to my org, but I get an error when I try to load the page. 
This is the error that I am getting:

`afterRender threw an error in 'c:forms' [Cannot read property 'values' of undefined]`

My JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import applicationObject from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c";
import medicalReleasePickList from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c.AIS_Medical_Release__c";
import travelFormPickList from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c.AIS_Travel_Form_Received__c";
import risingGradeLevelPickList from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c.AIS_Rising_Grade_Level__c";
import applicationYearPickList from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c.AIS_Outreach_Application_Year__c";
import programPickList from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c.TargetX_SRMb__Program__c";
import sessionAssignedPickList from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c.TargetX_SRMb__Application_Type__c";
import assignStatusPickList from "@salesforce/schema/TargetX_SRMb__Application__c.TargetX_SRMb__Status__c";
import getStudentData from "@salesforce/apex/applicationSearch.getValues";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  //track all html inputs
  @track firstName;
  @track lastName;
  @track ssn;
  @track state;
  @track initData;
  @track students;

  //get application object
  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: applicationObject })
  objectInfo;

  //track picklist values pre SOQL
  @track risingGradeLevelPickListValue;
  @track applicationYearPickListValue;
  @track programPickListValue;
  @track sessionAssignedPickListValue;
  @track assignStatusPickListValue;

  //get rising grade release pcklist values from server
  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: risingGradeLevelPickList
  })
  risingGradeLevelPickListValues;

  //get application year pcklist values from server
  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: applicationYearPickList
  })
  applicationYearPickListValues;

  //get program year pcklist values from server
  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: programPickList
  })
  programPickListValues;

  //get session assigned year pcklist values from server
  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: sessionAssignedPickList
  })
  sessionAssignedPickListValues;

  //get session assigned year pcklist values from server
  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: assignStatusPickList
  })
  assignStatusPickListValues;

  //init PRE SOQL picklist name handler
  handleRisingGradeValueChange(event) {
    this.risingGradeLevelPickListValue = event.detail.value;
  }

  handleApplicationYearPickListValueChange(event) {
    this.applicationYearPickListValue = event.detail.value;
  }

  handleProgramValueChange(event) {
    this.programPickListValue = event.detail.value;
  }

  handleSessionAssignedValueChange(event) {
    this.sessionAssignedPickListValue = event.detail.value;
  }

  handleAssignStatusValueChange(event) {
    this.assignStatusPickListValue = event.detail.value;
  }

  //track picklist values post SOQL
  @track medicalPickListValue;
  @track travelPickListValue;

  //get medical release picklist values from server
  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: medicalReleasePickList
  })
  medicalReleasePickListValues;

  //get medical release picklist values from server
  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: travelFormPickList
  })
  travelReleasePickListValues;

  //init POST SOQL picklist name handlers
  handleMedicalValueChange(event) {
    this.medicalPickListValue = event.detail.value;
  }

  handletravelValueChange(event) {
    this.travelPickListValue = event.detail.value;
  }

  //init input name handlers
  firstNameHandler(event) {
    this.firstName = event.target.value;
  }

  lastNameHandler(event) {
    this.lastName = event.target.value;
  }
  ssnHandler(event) {
    this.ssn = event.target.value;
  }
  stateHandler(event) {
    this.state = event.target.value;
  }

  //call responseback for if:true temp
  get responseback() {
    //show if data from apex class
    if (this.students) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  handleClick() {
    //call apex class with html values as params

    getStudentData({
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
      ssn: this.ssn,
      gradeLevel: this.risingGradeLevelPickListValue,
      appYear: this.applicationYearPickListValue,
      programName: this.programPickListValue,
      sessionAssigned: this.sessionAssignedPickListValue,
      assignStatus: this.assignStatusPickListValue,
      state: this.state
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.students = response;
        console.log(response);
        console.log(this.students.length);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error in fetching student records", error.body.message);
      });
  }
}
```

My HTML

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
    <h3 slot="title">
      <lightning-icon
        icon-name="standard:contact"
        size="small"
        class="slds-m-right_small"
      ></lightning-icon>
      Student Search
      <lightning-button-group class="slds-float_right">
        <lightning-button label="Refresh"></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button
          label="Search"
          onclick={handleClick}
        ></lightning-button>
      </lightning-button-group>
    </h3>
    <div class="slds-grid">
      <div class="slds-col slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small">
        <lightning-input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          label="First Name"
          onchange={firstNameHandler}
        ></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          label="Last Name"
          onchange={lastNameHandler}
        ></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input
          type="text"
          name="ssn"
          label="Last Four # of SSN"
          onchange={ssnHandler}
        ></lightning-input>
        <lightning-combobox
          name="risingGrade"
          label="Rising Grade Level"
          value={risingGradeLevelPickListValue}
          placeholder="-Select-"
          options={risingGradeLevelPickListValues.data.values}
          onchange={handleRisingGradeValueChange}
        >
        </lightning-combobox>
        <lightning-combobox
          name="applicationYear"
          label="Application Year"
          value={applicationYearPickListValue}
          placeholder="-Select-"
          options={applicationYearPickListValues.data.values}
          onchange={handleApplicationYearPickListValueChange}
        >
        </lightning-combobox>
        <lightning-combobox
          name="programName"
          label="Program Name"
          value={programPickListValue}
          placeholder="-Select-"
          options={programPickListValues.data.values}
          onchange={handleProgramValueChange}
        >
        </lightning-combobox>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col slds-p-right_small">
        <lightning-combobox
          name="sessionAssigned"
          label="Session Assigned"
          value={sessionAssignedPickListValue}
          placeholder="-Select-"
          options={sessionAssignedPickListValues.data.values}
          onchange={handleSessionAssignedValueChange}
        >
        </lightning-combobox>
        <lightning-combobox
          name="assignStatus"
          label="Assign Status"
          value={assignStatusPickListValue}
          placeholder="-Select-"
          options={assignStatusPickListValues.data.values}
          onchange={handleAssignStatusValueChange}
        >
        </lightning-combobox>
        <lightning-input
          type="text"
          name="state"
          label="State"
          onchange={stateHandler}
        ></lightning-input>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
      <!-- render template if search button is clicked -->
      <template if:true={responseback}>
        <ul class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <template for:each={students} for:item="student">
            <li key={student.Id}>
              {student.TargetX_SRMb__Contact__r.FirstName}
              {student.TargetX_SRMb__Contact__r.LastName}
              <lightning-combobox
                name="medicalPicklist"
                label="Medical Form"
                value={medicalPickListValue}
                placeholder="-Select-"
                options={medicalReleasePickListValues.data.values}
                onchange={handleMedicalValueChange}
              >
              </lightning-combobox>
              <lightning-combobox
                name="travelPicklist"
                label="Travel Form"
                value={travelPickListValue}
                placeholder="-Select-"
                options={travelReleasePickListValues.data.values}
                onchange={handletravelValueChange}
              >
              </lightning-combobox>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </template>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the picklist values have loaded, as demonstrated in the [demo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetPicklistValues/wireGetPicklistValues.html).

```
    <template if:true={risingGradeLevelPicklistValues.data}>
    <lightning-combobox
      name="risingGrade"
      label="Rising Grade Level"
      value={risingGradeLevelPickListValue}
      placeholder="-Select-"
      options={risingGradeLevelPickListValues.data.values}
      onchange={handleRisingGradeValueChange}
    >
   </template>
```